# $k$-th term of the sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to solve this:

> Find the $k$-th of the sequence
>
> $$-\frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{9}, -\frac{4}{27}, \frac{5}{81}...$$

I am not sure how to solve this, but I did the following thoughts:

- the numerator is an arithmetic sequence with ${a_1}=2$ and $d=1$. Therefore I could use the formula $2+(k-1)=k+1$
- the denominator is a geometric sequence with ${a_1}=3$ and $q=3$. Therefore: $3 * 3^{k -1}$.
  Hence, I my solution looks like this: $\frac{k + 1}{3 * 3^{k -1}}$

I suppose, $(-1)$ should be also included to give negative fractions...
Could you please help me to find out my mistake?

Comment: why not write $3 \cdot 3^{k-1}=3^k$

Comment: I see no mistake other than adding the $(-1)^k$ factor

Comment: How did you come up with $3^k$ ? I thought this expression $3 \cdot 3^{k-1}=3^k$ can not be further simplify.

Comment: it's just the law of exponents.  Here we have $$3 \cdot 3^{k-1}=3^k \implies$$ $$3^{1+(k-1)}=3^k$$

Answer (score 0):

We want the sign to alternate:

$$a_k = (-1)^k \frac{k+1}{3^k}=\frac{k+1}{(-3)^k}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_k=(-1)^k\frac{k + 1}{3^k}$$
could be one of the solution you are looking for